# Upload image and file

Tags: php

```
enter code here

<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn_uplaodpic']))
{
    $id = $_POST['hf_uname'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"images/".$id.".jpg");
    echo "Successfully upload!";
}
?>
```

Above is the code for upload image?

Is that the correct code for it?

Answer (score 1):

to upload an image from input and post with `#submit` button.

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image
        $target_path = "uploads/";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");  //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];//set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
                printf("<script>location.href='drag.php'</script>.");
            } else {//if file was not moved.
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">Only JPG, JPEG, PNG and GIF files types allowed.</span><br/><br/>';
            }     
        } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This will target a path, validate the file type to see whether it is an image or not. This will also allocate a random unique id name to each image when it's uploaded in uploads. it'll validate file size and display an error if it isn't an image or file size is too big.

CSS for errors.

```
#noerror{
    color:green;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align: left;
}
#error{
    color:red;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align: left;
}
```